# Merging two maps

Tags: apex

Given a map and the apex map method putAll()

```
map<String,Integer> intsByKey = new map<String,Integer> 
   {'a' => 1, 'b' => 2};
intsByKey.putAll(new map<String,Integer> 
   {'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'a' => 10});
```

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm?search_text=map%20class) states that putAll replaces the contents of the target map

> The new mappings from fromMap replace any mappings that the original
> map had.

So, how does one merge two maps in a convenient way?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well, conveniently for us, the documentation is misleading/ambiguous and `putAll` does a true merge.

```
map<String,Integer> intsByKey = new map<String,Integer> 
   {'a' => 1, 'b' => 2};
intsByKey.putAll(new map<String,Integer> 
   {'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'a' => 10});
```

The value of `intsByKey` after the second statement is:

```
{a=10, b=2, c=3, d=4}
```

That is, `putAll` acts like `addAll` does for lists/sets

Props to [Scott Hung's blog](https://scotthung.wordpress.com/2014/07/09/apex-maps-putall-method-documentation-error/) for saving me the trouble of writing a for loop

Comment: I think you misunderstood the statement (it's kind of ambiguous). What it's saying is that if a particular key is already in both maps, the one in the map you call putAll on will gain the new value.

Comment: Thinking about it, make sure you leave feedback on that page for the documentation team; they need to fix it, because it's clearly misleading.

Comment: The statement makes sense, ONLY AFTER, you realize what it is doing lol

Comment: actually, I have to agree with @sfdcfox - had I read the doc example more carefully, then I would see that it does what one wants.

Comment: Ahh yes. I did not look at the example. With that context it does make sense.

Comment: @sfdcfox doc feedback dutifully filed